# Tensorflow crashes whenever I try to run anything with a CNN architecture

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

Here are the logs.
I've tried everything, I've been running it on colab as an alternative, but I'd prefer this. Please help, I've got a GTX1650.
`Visual Studio Code (1.76.0, undefined, desktop)
Jupyter Extension Version: 2023.2.1000592019.
Python Extension Version: 2023.4.0.
No workspace folder opened.
User belongs to experiment group 'jupyterTestcf'
User belongs to experiment group 'jupyterEnhancedDataViewer'
info 23:47:05.297: LSP Notebooks experiment is enabled
warn 23:47:09.724: Failed to get activated env vars with python c:\Python310\python.exe in 2472ms
info 23:47:09.741: Process Execution: > c:\Python310\python.exe -c "import site;print("USER_BASE_VALUE");print(site.USER_SITE);print("USER_BASE_VALUE");"

> c:\Python310\python.exe -c "import site;print("USER_BASE_VALUE");print(site.USER_SITE);print("USER_BASE_VALUE");"
> info 23:47:10.047: Process Execution: > c:\Python310\python.exe -m pip list
> c:\Python310\python.exe -m pip list
> info 00:01:52.425: Starting Jupyter Session startUsingPythonInterpreter, .jvsc74a57bd0369f2c481f4da34e4445cda3fffd2e751bd1c4d706f27375911949ba6bb62e1c.c:\Python310\python.exe.c:\Python310\python.exe.-m#ipykernel_launcher (Python Path: , EnvType: Unknown, EnvName: '', Version: 3.10.2 (tags/v3.10.2:a58ebcc, Jan 17 2022, 14:12:15) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]) for 'd:\Desktop\MUJ\3rd Year\Sem 6\ACD Lab\test.ipynb' (disableUI=false)
> warn 00:01:52.591: Failed to get activated env vars with python c:\Python310\python.exe in 149ms
> info 00:01:52.598: Process Execution: > c:\Python310\python.exe -m pip list
> c:\Python310\python.exe -m pip list
> warn 00:01:52.599: Failed to get activated env vars with python c:\Python310\python.exe in 154ms
> info 00:01:52.612: Process Execution: > c:\Python310\python.exe -c "import ipykernel; print(ipykernel.**version**); print("5dc3a68c-e34e-4080-9c3e-2a532b2ccb4d"); print(ipykernel.**file**)"
> c:\Python310\python.exe -c "import ipykernel; print(ipykernel.**version**); print("5dc3a68c-e34e-4080-9c3e-2a532b2ccb4d"); print(ipykernel.**file**)"
> warn 00:01:52.613: Failed to get activated env vars with python c:\Python310\python.exe in 94ms
> warn 00:01:52.617: Failed to get activated env vars with python c:\Python310\python.exe in 97ms
> warn 00:01:52.698: Failed to get activated env vars with python c:\Python310\python.exe in 77ms
> info 00:01:52.716: Process Execution: > c:\Python310\python.exe ~.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1000592019\pythonFiles\vscode_datascience_helpers\kernel_interrupt_daemon.py --ppid 16956
> c:\Python310\python.exe ~.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1000592019\pythonFiles\vscode_datascience_helpers\kernel_interrupt_daemon.py --ppid 16956
> info 00:01:52.717: Process Execution: cwd: ~.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1000592019\pythonFiles\vscode_datascience_helpers
> cwd: ~.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1000592019\pythonFiles\vscode_datascience_helpers
> info 00:01:53.018: Process Execution: > c:\Python310\python.exe -m ipykernel_launcher --ip=127.0.0.1 --stdin=9003 --control=9001 --hb=9000 --Session.signature_scheme="hmac-sha256" --Session.key=b"47b76354-b2ec-4023-a0bc-7448c042ceca" --shell=9002 --transport="tcp" --iopub=9004 --f=c:\Users\ishan\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-v2-16956ncVA0UPo1y08.json
> c:\Python310\python.exe -m ipykernel_launcher --ip=127.0.0.1 --stdin=9003 --control=9001 --hb=9000 --Session.signature_scheme="hmac-sha256" --Session.key=b"47b76354-b2ec-4023-a0bc-7448c042ceca" --shell=9002 --transport="tcp" --iopub=9004 --f=c:\Users\ishan\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-v2-16956ncVA0UPo1y08.json
> info 00:01:53.018: Process Execution: cwd: d:\Desktop\MUJ\3rd Year\Sem 6\ACD Lab
> cwd: d:\Desktop\MUJ\3rd Year\Sem 6\ACD Lab
> info 00:01:53.805: ipykernel version & path 6.15.1, ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\ipykernel_*init*_.py for c:\Python310\python.exe
> info 00:01:56.211: Started Kernel Python 3.10.2 (pid: 7096)
> warn 00:01:56.297: Failed to get activated env vars with python c:\Python310\python.exe in 52ms
> info 00:01:56.303: Process Execution: > c:\Python310\python.exe ~.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1000592019\pythonFiles\printJupyterDataDir.py
> c:\Python310\python.exe ~.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1000592019\pythonFiles\printJupyterDataDir.py
> info 00:01:57.124: Cancel all remaining cells true || Error || undefined
> info 11:45:10.355: Starting Jupyter Session startUsingPythonInterpreter, .jvsc74a57bd0369f2c481f4da34e4445cda3fffd2e751bd1c4d706f27375911949ba6bb62e1c.c:\Python310\python.exe.c:\Python310\python.exe.-m#ipykernel_launcher (Python Path: , EnvType: Unknown, EnvName: '', Version: 3.10.2 (tags/v3.10.2:a58ebcc, Jan 17 2022, 14:12:15) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]) for 'd:\Desktop\MUJ\3rd Year\ACM Datathon\archive\Kindey_Stone_Dataset\kidneystone-acm.ipynb' (disableUI=false)
> warn 11:45:10.687: Failed to get activated env vars with python c:\Python310\python.exe in 309ms
> info 11:45:10.705: Process Execution: > c:\Python310\python.exe -c "import ipykernel; print(ipykernel.**version**); print("5dc3a68c-e34e-4080-9c3e-2a532b2ccb4d"); print(ipykernel.**file**)"
> c:\Python310\python.exe -c "import ipykernel; print(ipykernel.**version**); print("5dc3a68c-e34e-4080-9c3e-2a532b2ccb4d"); print(ipykernel.**file**)"
> warn 11:45:10.706: Failed to get activated env vars with python c:\Python310\python.exe in 182ms
> info 11:45:10.725: Process Execution: > c:\Python310\python.exe -m pip list
> c:\Python310\python.exe -m pip list
> warn 11:45:10.728: Failed to get activated env vars with python c:\Python310\python.exe in 154ms
> warn 11:45:10.733: Failed to get activated env vars with python c:\Python310\python.exe in 158ms
> info 11:45:10.770: Process Execution: > c:\Python310\python.exe -m ipykernel_launcher --ip=127.0.0.1 --stdin=9008 --control=9006 --hb=9005 --Session.signature_scheme="hmac-sha256" --Session.key=b"381e8dd2-0d07-4c91-9623-f328023240cb" --shell=9007 --transport="tcp" --iopub=9009 --f=c:\Users\ishan\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-v2-16956qcq0kVffHgle.json
> c:\Python310\python.exe -m ipykernel_launcher --ip=127.0.0.1 --stdin=9008 --control=9006 --hb=9005 --Session.signature_scheme="hmac-sha256" --Session.key=b"381e8dd2-0d07-4c91-9623-f328023240cb" --shell=9007 --transport="tcp" --iopub=9009 --f=c:\Users\ishan\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-v2-16956qcq0kVffHgle.json
> info 11:45:10.770: Process Execution: cwd: d:\Desktop\MUJ\3rd Year\ACM Datathon\archive\Kindey_Stone_Dataset
> cwd: d:\Desktop\MUJ\3rd Year\ACM Datathon\archive\Kindey_Stone_Dataset
> info 11:45:11.732: ipykernel version & path 6.15.1, ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\ipykernel_*init*_.py for c:\Python310\python.exe
> warn 11:45:13.824: StdErr from Kernel Process C:\Users\ishan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py:2392: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around strings is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. You can use 'hmac-sha256' instead of '"hmac-sha256"' if you require traitlets >=5.
> warn(

warn 11:45:13.825: StdErr from Kernel Process C:\Users\ishan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py:2346: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around Bytes is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. Use '381e8dd2-0d07-4c91-9623-f328023240cb' instead of 'b"381e8dd2-0d07-4c91-9623-f328023240cb"'.
warn(

info 11:45:14.187: Started Kernel Python 3.10.2 (pid: 10664)
info 11:45:51.658: Dispose Kernel 'd:\Desktop\MUJ\3rd Year\ACM Datathon\archive\Kindey_Stone_Dataset\kidneystone-acm.ipynb' associated with 'd:\Desktop\MUJ\3rd Year\ACM Datathon\archive\Kindey_Stone_Dataset\kidneystone-acm.ipynb'
info 11:45:51.661: Dispose Kernel process 10664.
error 11:45:51.686: Error in waiting for cell to complete [Error: Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done
at t.KernelShellFutureHandler.dispose (c:\Users\ishan.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1000592019\out\extension.node.js:2:33213)
at Fg. (c:\Users\ishan.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1000592019\out\extension.node.js:24:21202)
at f.invoke (d:\New Programs(x84)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:63:145)
at g.deliver (d:\New Programs(x84)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:63:2066)
at h.fire (d:\New Programs(x84)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:63:1704)
at d:\New Programs(x84)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:98:9583
at f.invoke (d:\New Programs(x84)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:63:145)
at g.deliver (d:\New Programs(x84)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:63:2066)
at h.fire (d:\New Programs(x84)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:63:1704)
at g.acceptDocumentsAndEditorsDelta (d:\New Programs(x84)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:98:13775)
at g.$acceptDocumentsAndEditorsDelta (d:\New Programs(x84)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:98:12249)
at u.$acceptDocumentAndEditorsDelta (d:\New Programs(x84)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:98:83232)
at c.N (d:\New Programs(x84)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:106:11223)
at c.M (d:\New Programs(x84)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:106:10941)
at c.H (d:\New Programs(x84)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:106:10034)
at c.G (d:\New Programs(x84)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:106:9172)
at d:\New Programs(x84)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:106:7803
at f.invoke (d:\New Programs(x84)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:63:145)
at g.deliver (d:\New Programs(x84)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:63:2066)
at h.fire (d:\New Programs(x84)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:63:1704)
at p.fire (d:\New Programs(x84)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:72:14907)
at d:\New Programs(x84)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:122:16556
at f.invoke (d:\New Programs(x84)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:63:145)
at g.deliver (d:\New Programs(x84)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:63:2066)
at h.fire (d:\New Programs(x84)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:63:1704)
at p.fire (d:\New Programs(x84)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:72:14907)
at MessagePortMain. (d:\New Programs(x84)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:122:14682)
at MessagePortMain.emit (node:events:526:28)
at MessagePortMain._internalPort.emit (node:electron/js2c/utility_init:5:364)]
warn 11:45:51.689: Cell completed with errors {
message: 'Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done'
}
info 11:45:51.691: Cancel all remaining cells true || Idle || undefined
info 11:46:37.891: Starting Jupyter Session startUsingPythonInterpreter, .jvsc74a57bd0369f2c481f4da34e4445cda3fffd2e751bd1c4d706f27375911949ba6bb62e1c.c:\Python310\python.exe.c:\Python310\python.exe.-m#ipykernel_launcher (Python Path: , EnvType: Unknown, EnvName: '', Version: 3.10.2 (tags/v3.10.2:a58ebcc, Jan 17 2022, 14:12:15) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]) for 'd:\Desktop\MUJ\3rd Year\ACM Datathon\kidneystone-acm (2).ipynb' (disableUI=false)
warn 11:46:38.005: Failed to get activated env vars with python c:\Python310\python.exe in 113ms
info 11:46:38.014: Process Execution: > c:\Python310\python.exe -c "import ipykernel; print(ipykernel.**version**); print("5dc3a68c-e34e-4080-9c3e-2a532b2ccb4d"); print(ipykernel.**file**)"

> c:\Python310\python.exe -c "import ipykernel; print(ipykernel.**version**); print("5dc3a68c-e34e-4080-9c3e-2a532b2ccb4d"); print(ipykernel.**file**)"
> warn 11:46:38.018: Failed to get activated env vars with python c:\Python310\python.exe in 48ms
> warn 11:46:38.022: Failed to get activated env vars with python c:\Python310\python.exe in 51ms
> info 11:46:38.068: Process Execution: > c:\Python310\python.exe -m ipykernel_launcher --ip=127.0.0.1 --stdin=9008 --control=9006 --hb=9005 --Session.signature_scheme="hmac-sha256" --Session.key=b"945237b3-87de-4cf3-8529-48b0c5701c00" --shell=9007 --transport="tcp" --iopub=9009 --f=c:\Users\ishan\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-v2-169567m9UEBhuiYhQ.json
> c:\Python310\python.exe -m ipykernel_launcher --ip=127.0.0.1 --stdin=9008 --control=9006 --hb=9005 --Session.signature_scheme="hmac-sha256" --Session.key=b"945237b3-87de-4cf3-8529-48b0c5701c00" --shell=9007 --transport="tcp" --iopub=9009 --f=c:\Users\ishan\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-v2-169567m9UEBhuiYhQ.json
> info 11:46:38.068: Process Execution: cwd: d:\Desktop\MUJ\3rd Year\ACM Datathon
> cwd: d:\Desktop\MUJ\3rd Year\ACM Datathon
> info 11:46:38.835: ipykernel version & path 6.15.1, ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\ipykernel_*init*_.py for c:\Python310\python.exe
> info 11:46:41.144: Started Kernel Python 3.10.2 (pid: 4544)
> info 11:46:57.798: Cancel all remaining cells true || Error || undefined
> info 11:47:14.429: Cancel all remaining cells true || Error || undefined
> warn 11:47:34.412: StdErr from Kernel Process 2023-03-13 11:47:34.412234: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] T
> warn 11:47:34.413: StdErr from Kernel Process his TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in
> warn 11:47:34.414: StdErr from Kernel Process  performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
> To enable them in other operations, rebuil
> warn 11:47:34.415: StdErr from Kernel Process d TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.

warn 11:47:37.352: StdErr from Kernel Process 2023-03-13 11:47:37.352462: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1616] Created device /job:
warn 11:47:37.352: StdErr from Kernel Process localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 2132 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5

warn 11:48:04.341: StdErr from Kernel Process 2023-03-13 11:48:04.341156: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:384] Loaded cuDNN version 8500

error 11:48:06.475: Disposing session as kernel process died ExitCode: 3221226505, Reason: C:\Users\ishan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py:2392: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around strings is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. You can use 'hmac-sha256' instead of '"hmac-sha256"' if you require traitlets >=5.
warn(
C:\Users\ishan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py:2346: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around Bytes is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. Use '945237b3-87de-4cf3-8529-48b0c5701c00' instead of 'b"945237b3-87de-4cf3-8529-48b0c5701c00"'.
warn(
2023-03-13 11:47:34.412234: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-03-13 11:47:37.352462: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1616] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 2132 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5
2023-03-13 11:48:04.341156: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:384] Loaded cuDNN version 8500

info 11:48:06.477: Dispose Kernel process 4544.
error 11:48:06.479: Raw kernel process exited code: 3221226505
error 11:48:06.617: Error in waiting for cell to complete [Error: Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done
at t.KernelShellFutureHandler.dispose (c:\Users\ishan.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1000592019\out\extension.node.js:2:33213)
at c:\Users\ishan.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1000592019\out\extension.node.js:2:52265
at Map.forEach ()
at y._clearKernelState (c:\Users\ishan.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1000592019\out\extension.node.js:2:52250)
at y.dispose (c:\Users\ishan.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1000592019\out\extension.node.js:2:45732)
at c:\Users\ishan.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1000592019\out\extension.node.js:17:127079
at ee (c:\Users\ishan.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1000592019\out\extension.node.js:2:1552543)
at lh.dispose (c:\Users\ishan.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1000592019\out\extension.node.js:17:127055)
at ph.dispose (c:\Users\ishan.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1000592019\out\extension.node.js:17:134354)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)]
warn 11:48:06.617: Cell completed with errors {
message: 'Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done'
}
info 11:48:06.619: Cancel all remaining cells true || Error || undefined
error 11:53:55.121: Error in execution [Af [Error]: The kernel 'Python 3.10.2' died. Click [here](https://aka.ms/vscodeJupyterKernelCrash) for more info. View Jupyter log for further details.
at Mv.verifyKernelState (c:\Users\ishan.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1000592019\out\extension.node.js:24:151174)
at async Lv.executeCell (c:\Users\ishan.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1000592019\out\extension.node.js:24:161389)
at async Promise.all (index 0)
at async Lv.handleExecution (c:\Users\ishan.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1000592019\out\extension.node.js:24:158306)] {
category: 'unknown',
originalException: undefined,
kernelConnectionMetadata: Zs {
kind: 'startUsingPythonInterpreter',
kernelSpec: {
specFile: 'c:\Users\ishan\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1000592019\temp\jupyter\kernels\pythonjvsc74a57bd0369f2c481f4da34e4445cda3fffd2e751bd1c4d706f27375911949ba6bb62e1c\kernel.json',
interpreterPath: 'c:\Python310\python.exe',
isRegisteredByVSC: 'registeredByNewVersionOfExt',
name: 'pythonjvsc74a57bd0369f2c481f4da34e4445cda3fffd2e751bd1c4d706f27375911949ba6bb62e1c',
argv: [Array],
language: 'python',
executable: 'python',
display_name: 'Python 3',
metadata: [Object],
env: {}
},
interpreter: {
id: 'C:\PYTHON310\PYTHON.EXE',
sysPrefix: 'C:\Python310',
displayPath: [f],
envName: '',
displayName: '',
envType: 'Unknown',
version: [Object],
uri: [f]
},
id: '.jvsc74a57bd0369f2c481f4da34e4445cda3fffd2e751bd1c4d706f27375911949ba6bb62e1c.c:\Python310\python.exe.c:\Python310\python.exe.-m#ipykernel_launcher'
}
}
error 11:53:55.160: Error in execution (get message for cell) [Af [Error]: The kernel 'Python 3.10.2' died. Click [here](https://aka.ms/vscodeJupyterKernelCrash) for more info. View Jupyter log for further details.
at Mv.verifyKernelState (c:\Users\ishan.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1000592019\out\extension.node.js:24:151174)
at async Lv.executeCell (c:\Users\ishan.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1000592019\out\extension.node.js:24:161389)
at async Promise.all (index 0)
at async Lv.handleExecution (c:\Users\ishan.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1000592019\out\extension.node.js:24:158306)] {
category: 'unknown',
originalException: undefined,
kernelConnectionMetadata: Zs {
kind: 'startUsingPythonInterpreter',
kernelSpec: {
specFile: 'c:\Users\ishan\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1000592019\temp\jupyter\kernels\pythonjvsc74a57bd0369f2c481f4da34e4445cda3fffd2e751bd1c4d706f27375911949ba6bb62e1c\kernel.json',
interpreterPath: 'c:\Python310\python.exe',
isRegisteredByVSC: 'registeredByNewVersionOfExt',
name: 'pythonjvsc74a57bd0369f2c481f4da34e4445cda3fffd2e751bd1c4d706f27375911949ba6bb62e1c',
argv: [Array],
language: 'python',
executable: 'python',
display_name: 'Python 3',
metadata: [Object],
env: {}
},
interpreter: {
id: 'C:\PYTHON310\PYTHON.EXE',
sysPrefix: 'C:\Python310',
displayPath: [f],
envName: '',
displayName: '',
envType: 'Unknown',
version: [Object],
uri: [f]
},
id: '.jvsc74a57bd0369f2c481f4da34e4445cda3fffd2e751bd1c4d706f27375911949ba6bb62e1c.c:\Python310\python.exe.c:\Python310\python.exe.-m#ipykernel_launcher'
}
}
`

I tried close to everything I could find, The github solutions just did not work,
If it helps, WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip. appears when I try to reinstall tensorflow

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is the code you tried running which throws this error. Also please share the tensorflow , python version and the platform you are using (VS code, Jupyter or Google Colab etc.).